# how to send a value from a tag except input to a function?

Tags: javascript, html

hi I had a question that how can I send a value from a tag except for inputs ! to a javascript function
for getting identified ...

for example, I want to click on a tr tag in table (on screen) then send a value or name or something like that to a function then function starts identifying tag value or data ... for example if tag name or tag data or tag value was "tag1" it runs a function.
I searched before and saw many people use data-id but I don't know is it workable for me or not ...
then how can I use it.

```
<html>   
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td data-id = "td1" id = "td1" >
 
            </td>
            <td id = "td2"  >

            </td>
            <td id = "td3" >

            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td id = "td4" >

            </td>
            <td id = "td5" >

            </td>
            <td id = "td6" >
               
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td id = "td7" >

            </td>
            <td id = "td8" >

            </td>
            <td id = "td9" >
               
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <script>
      function clicked(){
         let x =  document.getElementById("td1").getAttribute("onclick")
      }
      </script>    
   </body>
</html>
```

here is the css code :

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
table {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;

}
table td {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Would you post what have you tried (including both javascript and HTML code)?

Comment: yes sure i added the html / js code  if you are seeing other elements are not just like td1 it's because i would to test the data-id but i dont know how exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you an example for your reference:

```js
let allTrs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (let i =0;i<allTrs.length;i++){
  allTrs[i].addEventListener("click",()=>{hello(allTrs[i])});
}
function hello(row){
    let cellList=row.cells;
  for (let i=0;i<cellList.length;i++){
    console.log("id="+cellList[i].id);
    console.log("data-id="+cellList[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
    console.log("text content="+cellList[i].textContent);
    console.log("=======================================");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
table {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;

}
table td {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="td1" id="td1">
        1
    </td>
    <td id="td2">
        2
    </td>
    <td id="td3">
        3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td4">
      4
    </td>
    <td id="td5">
      5
    </td>
    <td id="td6">
      6
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td7">
      7
    </td>
    <td id="td8">
      8
    </td>
    <td id="td9">
      9
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```